# Problem with ADBannerView

Tags: iphone, iad

a have a small problem when i want to skip from the first view to the second :
i have an ADBannerView1 in the first viewController, and another ADBannerView2 in the secondViewController..the problem is when i skip from the first to the second, half of the adBanner2 is hidden by the status bar...i've tried to delete the status bar, and put the scale to fit attribute in vain..
the problem is when i try to click on the adBanner2 and back to my secondView it will appear perfectly but not when it loaded :(
any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my problem i just found the solution : if you want to read the documentation : http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26

it's a BOOL property for the viewController that you want to display : wantsFullScreenLayout
you just have to put this code when you want to skip to the second ViewController :
secondview.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

hope it will help..